# How to compare two dataframes based on certain column values and remove them in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames.

df1:

```
userID    ID    Sex   Date   Month    Year   Security
  John    45   Male     31      03    1975        Low
   Tom    22   Male     01      01    1990       High
  Mary    33 Female     23      05    1990     Medium
  Hary    56   Male     15      09    1970       High
```

df2:

```
userID    ID    Sex   Date   Month    Year
  Hari    45   Male     31      03    1975
  Luka    22   Male     01      01    1990
 Johan    33 Female     23      05    1990
 Irfan    56   Male     29      09    1971
  John    45   Male     31      03    1975
   Tom    22   Male     01      01    1990
  Mary    34 Female     34      05    1980
  Hary    56   Male     15      09    1970
```

I wanted to compare df2 with df1 and keep only those rows in df2 which are having 
common values in columns (userID,ID,Date,Month,Year)

So my new df2 should look like this:

```
  John    45   Male     31      03    1975
   Tom    22   Male     01      01    1990
  Hary    56   Male     15      09    1970
```

What could be the best approach get this in pandas?
Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Did you also want to comparison to be on `Sex` or just those 5 columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do with simple `merge` follow with `dropna`

```
df2.merge(df1,how='left').dropna().drop('Security',1)
Out[318]: 
  userID  ID   Sex  Date  Month  Year
4   John  45  Male    31      3  1975
5    Tom  22  Male     1      1  1990
7   Hary  56  Male    15      9  1970
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the key columns which you want to merge on, and then perform an inner merge between `df2` and only the key columns of `df1`. The default for `merge` is inner, so you don't need to specify it explicitly. Subsetting `df1` to only these key columns ensures that you don't bring any of its columns over to `df2` with the merge.

```
key_cols = ['userID', 'ID', 'Date', 'Month', 'Year']
df2.merge(df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(key_cols)])
```

Outputs:

```
  userID  ID   Sex  Date  Month  Year
0   John  45  Male    31      3  1975
1    Tom  22  Male     1      1  1990
2   Hary  56  Male    15      9  1970
```